# Rails: update an attribute to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an integer column `post_id` that has a value in the db and I would like to update it to nil from the controller.

I have tried the following but unfortunately the value remains the same and does not change to nil:

```
current_user.account.update(post_id: nil)
current_user.account.update(post_id: 0)
```

Any ideas on how I can update the post id to nil?

**Update 1**

Account table

```
create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "street"
  t.string "city"
  t.string "state"
  t.string "postal_code"
  t.string "country"
  t.integer "post_id", default: 0
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

the link to:

```
<%= link_to "Remove post from user", remove_post_path, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

the route:

```
get "user/remove_post", to: "accounts#remove_post", :as => : remove_post
```

the controller method:

```
def remove_post
  current_user.account.update_attributes(post_id: nil)
end
```

What i get in the console:

```
Account Update (0.6ms)  UPDATE "accounts" SET "post_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "accounts"."id" = $3  [["post_id", 96], ["updated_at", "2019-02-27 10:43:53.432402"], ["id", 49]]
```

Comment: Could you provide your model defintions?

Comment: @mbuechmann ... If you mean the table schema, I have updated my question with this info. If you're talking about something else please let me know what. Please keep in mind that the column already has an integer value in it.

Comment: Also check this https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column

Comment: @Theopap no, I mean the model definition ;)

Comment: sorry @mbuechmann i have no idea what you're asking for. The associations?

Comment: Yes. But I see, you already posted that someplace else.

Comment: It would be much better, if you added all requested information to your question. At the moment these infos are all scattered around in a lot of comments. This makes answering your question a very hard piece of work.

Comment: Could you please add the whole controller action code?

Comment: @ mbuechmann i just update my question with all the info.

Comment: @Vasilisa i just updated my question with all the info.

Comment: @Theopap is it the only one `Account Update` line in the log? It is better to post the whole log. Maybe you have some callbacks in Account model?

Comment: Thats the only one I'm updating and in the console is not returning any callbacks.I know its weird. The question is can I update a integer column that has a value already to nil?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Try

```
ac = Account.first
ac.post_id = nil
ac.save(validate: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

I went with this:

```
Account.update(current_user.account.id, post_id: nil)
```

Let me know if another solution might be better.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have the relation between account and post. By default, Rails validates weather the relation exists. You can change this by adding `optional: true` to your model:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post, optional: true
end
```

After this, you can change successfully value of this column to nil.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @barmic, I already have this setup in my account model `belongs_to :post, optional: true`.

Comment: Are you receiving Rollback after trying to change?

Comment: `Account Update (0.5ms)  UPDATE "accounts" SET "post_id" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "accounts"."id" = $3  [["post_id", 94], ["updated_at", "2019-02-27 09:58:10.479125"], ["id", 47]]`

Comment: This is what i get... it seems like it keeps the existing value for some weird reason.

Comment: Maybe is something wrong with your controller? Try update record using the console.

Comment: The output indicates, that you are setting the the post_id to 94 not to nil.

Comment: It works fine when i do this form the console: `Account.find(47).update(post_id: nil)`

Comment: So the problem is with the controller probably. Could you post the action from the controller which is responsible for update?

Comment: @mbuechmann yes I know... but I'm doing this: `current_user.account.update_attributes(post_id: nil)` which should be correct.

Comment: Then you must be doing something else, too. Could you check on that? Also are you sure that you are calling this controller action?

Comment: @barmic this is all i have in the controller action : `current_user.account.update_attributes(post_id: nil)`

Comment: I am sure that this line does not get called. Then you must be in a different controller or action.